# Java library for reading database schema

Tags: java, jdbc, database-schema, ddlutils

I'm looking for a lightweight, open source, more or less cross-database Java library that would allow me to read off metainformation on columns, tables and integrity constraints given a `DataSource`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question, [Apache DDLUtils](http://db.apache.org/ddlutils/).
My question was really a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985010/easiest-way-to-obtain-database-metadata-in-java).

Answer (score 10):

Depends what you want to do afterwards of course, but if you just want to visualise an existing datatbase, I recommend [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/).

Of course, JDBC already lets you read metainformation, using `Connection.getMetaData()`. This gives you a [DatabaseMetaData](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) instance.