# Retrieving MYSQL Database structure information from Java

Tags: java, .net, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to do with java and mysql the same I am used to with .net and SQL server:

By using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo I can access database structure information from my instance ( server name, table structure, columns, datatype, description, default value)

I tried to find to do the same with Java + MYSQL but it seems it is not so popular

any directions?

thanks

Ed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish it is by retrying the connection metadata, first you open a connection:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "user","****");
DatabaseMetaData metaData = conn.getMetaData();
```

then start navigating through the metadata, you can check the available operations in [DatabaseMedata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

Answer (score 3):

[DatabaseMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) will be useful for your requirement.

please also check [nearly similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985010/easiest-way-to-obtain-database-metadata-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

use the DatabaseMetadata for get database related information.
[Database Metadata](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)