# Java SQL safely check if column exists

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I need to have dynamic SQL which accepts table and column names from users and uses those in queries. Right now I do this with

```
public Object doSearch(String table, List<String> columns) {
//... some logic
String.format("SELECT %s from %s", String.join(", ", columns), table");
//... some execution and return
}
```

The source is NOT trusted, so I want to do a whitelist of table and column names, but that list changes. The list of valid tables is strictly the list of tables on `my_schema` and the list of valid columns is strictly the columns on that particular table.

I've searched around SO and gotten a solution that looks something like:

```
private boolean validate(String tableName, List<String> columnNames) throws SQLException {
    return tableExist(tableName) && columnNames.stream().allMatch(cn -> columnExistsOnTable(tableName, cn));
}
private boolean tableExist(String tableName) throws SQLException {
    try (ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getTables(null, schema, tableName, null)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String tName = rs.getString("TABLE_NAME");
            if (tName != null && tName.equals(tableName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean columnExistsOnTable(String tableName, String columnName) {
    try (ResultSet rs = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, tableName, columnName)) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            String tName = rs.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
            if (tName != null && tName.equals(tableName)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is this safe and correct?

Comment: I think you can refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985010/easiest-way-to-obtain-database-metadata-in-java). You actually need to get the database definition in order to parse it and find the objects you need. This project might help you to work independently of data sources.

Answer (score 0):

For each of those methods, you could do this one time in an initialization method and cache the table/column names so you don't have to do a database check every time... something like this:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> tableColNames = new HashMap();


    private void initCache(){
       // build the cache


  // get all tables 
   // get all columns
   // add tables and columns to the map 
}


private boolean tableExist(String tableName) throws SQLException {
    return tableColNames.containsKey(tableName);
}

private boolean columnExistsOnTable(String tableName, String columnName) {
   if(tableExist(tableName)){
     return   tableColNames.get(tableName).contains(columnName);
   } else {
     return false;
   }

}
// could make a method for checking a list of Strings too...
// return tableColNames.get(tableName).containsAll(columnName);
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html